# "Subquery returns more than 1 value" when trying to INSERT

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to INSERT into a table a column that is part of another column in another table using TSQL, but I get the error stating that there is more than one value returned when I used that subquery as an expression. I understand what causes the error, but I can't seem to think of a way to make it produce what I want.

I'm trying to do something similar to:

```
A.Base      B.Reference  C.Wanted
---         ----         ----
abcdaa      aa           abcdaa
bcdeab      bb           cdefbb
cdefbb      cc           efghcc
defgbc      ddd          fghddd
efghcc
fghddd
```

So I'm using the code:

```
INSERT INTO C ( [Some other column], Wanted )
SELECT 
    A.[Some other column], 
    , CASE
        WHEN LEN( B.Reference ) = 2 THEN
            ( SELECT A.Base FROM A WHERE RIGHT( A.Base, 2 ) = 
                ( SELECT B.Reference FROM B WHERE LEN( B.Reference ) = 2 )
            )
        WHEN LEN( B.Reference ) = 3 THEN
            ( SELECT A.Base FROM A WHERE RIGHT( A.Base, 3 ) = 
                ( SELECT B.Reference FROM B WHERE LEN( B.Reference ) = 3 )
            )
    END
FROM 
    A
    , B
```

Which will return me the "more than 1 value" error. Honestly, I'm probably making this way more convoluted than it needs to be, but I've been staring at these tables for a while now.

I hope I'm getting the idea across as to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How are `A` and `B` joined with each other? At the moment you are joining every row of `A` with every row of `B`. Also, your embedded `SELECT`s are returning more than 1 result, hence the error you are receiving.

Comment: `A` and `B` are joined by `Base` and `Reference` actually, `Base` is just a composite of `Reference` and another column. Also, I understand why it's returning more than one result, I'm more so trying to get what in want in `C.Wanted` but I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the records aren't duplicate, and you are sure your JOIN between A and B works (as Martin mentioned) can't you just select distinct to return just the unique records?

Comment: I have tried, my full code actually does include a SELECT DISTINCT, but I still end up getting the
```Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
``` error

Honestly, I don't have to use this code, I just really don't know what other methods there are.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it like this:

--Create a *mockup* with declared table variables and test data

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(someColumnInA VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @tblB TABLE(someColumnInB VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @tblC TABLE(someColumnInC VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES
 ('abcdaa')   
,('bcdeab') 
,('cdefbb')   
,('defgbc')  
,('efghcc')
,('fghddd')

INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES
 ('aa')          
,('bb')          
,('cc')          
,('ddd');
```

--The query

```
INSERT INTO @tblC(someColumnInC)
SELECT SomeColumnInA
FROM @tblA a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblB b WHERE a.someColumnInA LIKE '%' + b.SomeColumnInB + '%');

SELECT * FROM  @tblC;
```

The idea in short:

After creating a *mockup* (please do this next time in advance) we use a query to insert all values from `@tblA` into `@tblC` as long as there exists any value in `@tblB`, which is part of the current value in `@tblA`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try that out

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this?

```
select *
from A
where RIGHT(A.Base,2) IN (select B.Reference FROM B WHERE LEN(B.Reference) = 2)

UNION ALL

select *
from A
where RIGHT(A.Base,3) IN (select B.Reference FROM B WHERE LEN(B.Reference) = 3)
```